# Django: Querying Model M2M with Users in

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model House, House has a many to many with User (called owners), and I'm looking to get all the houses a user owns (specifically the logged in user), the following:

```
House.objects.filter(owners__contains=request.user)
```

Yields an invalid lookup error, I'm assuming this is because it's meant to do a LIKE. Though I'm unsure how else I would retrieve this data. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code:

```
House.objects.filter(owners=request.user)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also, depending upon how your model is defined, use something like:

```
request.user.house_set.all()
```

This saves you having to import `House` into the current scope.

Note that if you defined your many-to-many with a related_name, you'd use that instead of `house_set`.